# font awesome is not loading in my apache

Tags: html, css, apache, ubuntu

font awesome is not working on my ubuntu apache but it working in localhost xamp.I have checked in both the server in my ubuntu vps it is not working  but working in local host can any one help me what changes i have to make in my apache config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you are looking for, problem may be in your file's path. try absolute path if font awesome file are stored on your server, or try cdn to include font awesome files.

```
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/0ed2d2b93d.js"></script>
```

Comment: this script i have to add in my index file

Answer (score 0):

I would make sure Apache is reporting the correct filetype for the font files. [Check here](https://github.com/EnlightenAgency/Server-Setup-MIME-Types-Headers/blob/master/font-mimetypes.txt).

Using a CDN might be a better option for you if you don't/can't get into the server configuration.

Comment: thanks for reply which file and path i have to make chnages

Comment: You will be referring to lines 29-37 in the github provided. You will need to add this to your .htaccess file.

Comment: do i have create .htaccess in etc/fonts  or any other location